# Listview Unable to update when inserting a new data from custom dialog

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, dialog

I'm trying to display data from SQLite database to a custom listview. The data is inserted from a custom dialog and the user click on the positive button it should update the listview, but the listview doesn't update. It only update when I click the back button and reenter the Activity. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly, you don't reload the data after user click on the positive button. You can override onResume method and add more code to update the data in the list and call [adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) to refresh the data in listview.

Comment: I tried your advice and put this code in onResume() and the ListView didnt update: 
arrayList.clear();
        arrayList.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllSubjectListData());
        subjectListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into your onResume()

```
databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
loadListView();
```

Actually there are many ways to get refresh data in recyclerview.
But in my experience i always do this because easy to use, and ofc work. you can try to understanding the lifecycle of android by this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: I already did tried this method and it does not work. I used Log.i to check and found out that when I launch the app and go to SubjectListActivity the compiler read both the onCreate and onResume. So when I insert data into the dialog, the Listview doesn't update.